# Do not connect oracle database with PHP through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

I want to connect the oracle Schema database by default that comes in the oracle bd through PDO with php but it throws me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect
>   identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:640) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ORACLE\52conexion3.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ORACLE\52conexion3.php(9):
>   PDO->__construct('oci:host=localh...', 'hr', 'hr') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ORACLE\52conexion3.php on line 9

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost/XE; dbname= Schema - HR', 'hr','hr');

?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the sql developer in the connection where is the bd of "shema" I gave a right click to see properties and that the data I entered is correct, it says Connection name: **Schema - HR**, user: **hr**, password: **hr**, alias of the network: **XE** .

Other attempts and still not working:

```
$base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost;dbname=Schema - HR', 'hr','hr');

$base = new PDO("oci:host=localhost;dbname=Schema - HR", "hr","hr");

$base = new PDO("oci:host=localhost/XE;dbname=Schema - HR", "hr","hr");

$base = new PDO("oci:host=XE;dbname=Schema - HR", "hr","hr");

$base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost;dbname="Schema - HR"', 'hr','hr');
```

I checked the .ini file and it's apparently right "extension = php_pdo_oci.dll".

**NOTE:** I searched the php manual and when I do not connect with pdo but through the procedure I do it in this way (using oci_connect) and it works correctly:

$ connection = oci_connect ('hr', 'hr', 'localhost / XE');

// oci_connect: resource oci_connect (string $ username, string $ password [, string $ connection_string [, string $ character_set [, int $ session_mode]])

Comment: As a guess - it does not like the spaces in the database name.

Comment: I tried with other database (with name without spaces "prueba" but also doesn´t work :/

Comment: What is this "localhost/XE" syntax? `host` should be the name of the host, which should be a (DNS) resolvable name; it shouldn't contain slashes.

Comment: You could also try using `127.0.0.1` or the external IP.

Comment: I saw in a forum that they put it that way, but I tried in many ways (see the end of the post).

Comment: I searched the in the php manual when I do not connect with pdo but through the procedure I do it in this way and it works correctly:

$ connection = oci_connect ('hr', 'hr', 'localhost / XE');

// oci_connect: resource oci_connect (string $ username, string $ password [, string $ connection_string [, string $ character_set [, int $ session_mode]])

Comment: Not sure if the PDO Oracle driver handles/splits the hostname specifically: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c#L587 - But the manual says it belongs in the `dbname=` param: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php

Comment: Have you tried this: https://gist.github.com/odan/4edb46a44721f2ef3bdefe2ea999e2e8

Comment: Yes daniel O, using oci_connect I can connect to database perfectly, but i want to connect it using PDO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented on the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php), and [mentioned in a comment by mario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501277/do-not-connect-oracle-database-with-php-through-pdo#comment81958682_47501277), a PDO DSN for OCI uses `dbname`, not `schema` or `host`, in its definition:

```
$conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/XE', $user, $pass);
```

The `localhost/XE` format you are using is an '[EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT)' string. The first part defines the host (localhost) and the second part the service (XE).

You could also use a 'regular' connection string (as normally defined in a `tnsnames.ora` file) instead:

```
$conn_string = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))';
$conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=' . $conn_string, $user, $pass);
```

Comment: I thought that for both oracle and mysql it was the same, I was watching a PDO tutorial (but they used a mysql bd with phpmyadmin) and they put 4 fields (as I wrote in the topic). Apparently they are different and with ORACLE only 3 fields are needed :) is it correct? Now it works for me but I would like to leave the doubt.
Note: I tried putting
$ conn = new PDO ('oci: dbname = localhost', $ user, $ pass);
Without the XE and it works well, why is it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm) shows all parts of the connection string, except `host`, as optional.  Quote: _If a user specifies a service name, then the listener connects the user to that specific database. Otherwise, the listener connects to the database specified by the `DEFAULT_SERVICE_listener_name` parameter in the `listener.ora` file._

Answer (score 0):

If you're using localhost and set TNS, you can use just a connection alias, in my case `orcl`:

```
$conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=orcl', $user, $pass);
```

On remote, you can:

```
$conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=hostname', $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score -1):

in your php folder there is php.ini file open it in notepad and remove the extensions before statements who have oci in front then start server again and then run your code.

for connectivity you need to add:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type");

 $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $_POST = json_decode($rest_json,true);

 $opt   = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                       );
   // Create a PDO instance (connect to the database)
   $pdo     = new PDO('oci:dbname=127.0.0.1/xe;charset=CL8MSWIN1251', 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!